Why Job family is not showing when I upload data via positions entity in D365 finance and operations?
I'm trying to create positions in D365 F&O via data entity (HcmPositionV2Entity), but once the upload is done, I can't see the job family related to the job in the positions form? :(Example: P_003) in the bellow screenshut:

But instead when I create the position directly in D365, the family job is showing well (Ex: P_001 and P_002)
